# Copy Activity Properties to update Azure DW data from an on prem SQL stored procedure in data factory

Tags: sql, etl, data-warehouse, azure-data-factory

I'm not sure that what I'm trying to achieve is even possible in Data factory, but I guess there should be a way. 
Simply put it, I have a table in DW that needs to be updated by a stored procedure once a day.

This stored procedure resides on the Source DB, I am looking for a way to pass some IDs and get the results from that SP and store it in DB.

Any Help would be appreciated. Below Pipeline is all I could think of:

```
     {
"name": "UpdateColumnX",
"properties": {

    "activities": [
        {
            "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure?? Not Really Sure",
            "typeProperties": {
            "source": {
                    "type": "SqlSource",
                    "sqlReaderQuery": "$$Text.Format('Passing IDs to the stored Procedure', Time.AddHours(WindowStart,10), Time.AddHours(WindowEnd,10))\n"
                },
                "storedProcedureName": "UpdateDataThroughSP",
                "storedProcedureParameters": {
                    "StartDate": "$$Text.Format('{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}', Time.AddHours(WindowStart,10))",
                    "EndDate ": "$$Text.Format('{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}', Time.AddHours(WindowEnd,10))"
                }
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "Not Sure which table should be my Input, the DW table having the IDs or the source table? "
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "Sames and Input not sure"
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "01:00:00",
                "concurrency": 1,
                "retry": 3
            },
            "scheduler": {
                "frequency": "Day",
                "interval": 1,
                "offset": "20:30:00"
            },
            "name": "Update Data through Source SP"
        }
    ],
    "start": "2017-09-13T20:30:00.045Z",
    "end": "2099-12-30T13:00:00Z",
    "isPaused": false,
    "hubName": "HubName",
    "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
}
}
```

Comment: I'm almost certain this is not possible, or very difficult in Data Factory. Are the source and target databases on the cloud? Do you have to use data factory? Is this a scheduled task or user triggered? I used Data Factory for some time but eventually it could not fulfill my particular requirements so instead I used Powershell inside Azure Automation to orchestrate and run everything.

Comment: Where do you get the id's from that you pass into the stored procedure? Does this all have to run on the cloud?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks for your comments, The easiest way would be doing this inside data factory. The IDs are coming from a different data base and I can't run the stored procedure on extraction. They should first come into the staging area, then I'll be able to pass them back to another data base and get the result. None of our DB sources are on the cloud. But our DW is on the cloud

Comment: I still don't quite understand whats going where or how many databases we're dealing with. Anyway if you have on prem databases pushing into a cloud database, you don't need to use data factory at all. If you have a cloud database pulling data into it from on prem then data factory is an option, but it is really not very good at certain things. (or it _can_ be done but it's overcomplicated).

Comment: Right now I couldn't begin to suggest anything because I can't understand what's going where. But if you were to explain completely I would probably suggest a non ADF solution anyway

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid It's actually quite simple, I have a table in DW, I want to update a column of this table using a stored procedure in a source DB.

Comment: and the stored procedure takes parameters, those being a (variable?) number of id's. Reading through your json, it looks like these id's come out of the DW, is that right? So we only have a total of two databases at play here?

Comment: and if its a variable number of id's, what kind of parameter is your stored procedure using? a table valued parameter or seperated id's in a string?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid There's a stored procedure which passes each ID into a scalar function and returns a value for each ID, I might need to create a loop to get all the IDs into that function. Anyway, My problem is that I have no idea what kind of activity I need and how to configure that to get the result of that

Comment: If you look around for suggestions online on how to build a ADF source that can do anything out of the ordinary (i.e. get data in loops ) you'll find suggestions of creating a a custom data source in C#, housed in Azure batch .to me this is _completely over the top_ and is a good indicator that you're using the wrong tool or an immature tool. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/cloud-development/creating-custom-net-activity-pipeline-azure-data-factory/

Comment: So I'll put it to you: 1. ADF is the wrong tool; 2. I can probably pose a solution in a different architecture but after all of this dialog there still isn't enough specifics for me to suggest anything.

Comment: Can we forget about Data Factory for a moment?  Try and describe what you want to do without referencing it.  How about a diagram?